# Copy text with bullets in OpenXml

Tags: .net, vb.net, openxml, wordprocessingml

I have the following problem:

*Text needs to be copied from 1 wordprocessing document to another wordprocessing document.  The source document is not always accessible when inserting the text in the target part.  The text is serialized and retrieved later on.*

They way I currently do this is by copying the paragraphs elements and then appending them into the other document.  This works fine unless bullets are involved.  **The bullets are not copied from the source to the target document.**

Here is some example code:

```
Public Sub SerializeParagraphsBetweenBookmark(ByVal stream As Stream)
    Dim wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(_fileLocation, True)
    Dim paragraphsFromBookmarks As IEnumerable(Of Paragraph)
    Using (wordDoc)
        paragraphsFromBookmarks = GetAllParagraphFromBookmarks(wordDoc)
    End Using
    SerializeParagraphsToFile(paragraphsFromBookmarks, stream)
End Sub

Private Sub SerializeParagraphsToFile(ByVal paragraphsFromBookmarks As IEnumerable(Of Paragraph), stream As Stream)
    ' the IEnumerable of paragraphs must be converted to an IEnumerable of strings before it can be converted
    Dim serializableIEnumerable = paragraphsFromBookmarks.Select(Function(x) x.OuterXml).ToList()
    Dim binSerializer As New BinaryFormatter()
    binSerializer.Serialize(stream, serializableIEnumerable)
End Sub
```

Then when I retrieve them, I add them to the target file like so:

```
Public Sub InsertParagraphsInDocument(paragraphs As IEnumerable(Of Paragraph))
    Dim wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(_fileLocation, True)
    Using (wordDoc)
        Dim rootElement = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement
        Dim bookmark = rootElement.Descendants(Of BookmarkStart).FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name.Value.Equals(_pasteBookmark))
        Dim paragraphsList = paragraphs.ToList()
        For i As Integer = paragraphsList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            bookmark.Parent.InsertAfterSelf(paragraphsList(i))
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

The code is nothing fancy and any improvement suggestions are welcome.

I know that bullets are stored in the **NumberingDefinitionsPart** of the MainDocument part but my problem is how do I know which AbstractNum and NumberingInstance to insert in this NumberingDefinitionsPart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself, it seems I had to synchronize the numbering definition part between the two files.

I wrote a tool that does this so if anyone is interested, check it out: http://www.lucbos.net/2011/11/wordprocessing-serialization-move.html

Comment: Hi Luc, I'm interested by your code. Your link is broken, have you moved your post ?

Comment: Hi pierre, that's an old piece of code that you want :-p You can find the link here: http://strugglesofacoder.blogspot.be/2011/11/wordprocessing-serialization-move.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Luc, I solved my issue 2 days ago. It was the same kind of code. Cheers ;)